# Moment.js - How to access 'moment' function from a moment object?

Tags: momentjs

Let's say I've got a `moment` object, created by calling `moment()`.

**How can I access the original `moment` function from this object ?**

The challenge here is in a case where I cannot import or access `moment` directly. For instance, in a pure function, receiving nothing else than a `moment` object as parameter.

Good to know:
I tried the constructor but this is not the function:
`moment().constructor !== moment` ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the function as parameter?

```js
const moment = require("moment");

const somePureFunc = (moment, date) => {
  return moment(date);
}

console.log(somePureFunc(moment, new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for your try. I've thought about it, but I'm not able to. My function is used as a [calendar callback](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/), and moment passes only one instance of moment as parameter and nothing else.